# Shirk,kufr matter of aqeedah in the field of islamic matters

Tags: shirk, kufr

1. I study in Hindu school and there are kufr prayers in that school in the morning assembly i remained in their but i didn't take part in those prayers nor clasped the hands like theirs and u hated in my heart . Is this Shirk/kufr ? There is no Islamic school near me and my parents are forcing me to go to this school and i have not any option but to go to this school. And i also cannot left the school because I am in 10th if i left the school i have to study the whole two years starting from 9th and might be my father didn't get my admission done into another school.
2. I did not do that kufr prayers nor clasped hands like theirs but my teacher is now scolding me then i have said her that i have so much pain in my hands and in reality also I had so much pain in my hand.so my teacher said that give me a letter stating the problem and with the medical certificate (although i have) and to state that when I have been praying kufr prayers.I have almost 4 months left in this school. So is it right for me to send her application with medical certificate until i pass the school.Is there any harm upon me in future?

Answer (score 0):

Salam Brother,

because Shirk is the first major sin in Islam, you need to stand your ground on this one. Talk with your teacher about your faith, explain that you do not want to participate because you're a Muslim. If you are telling the truth about your hand, feel free to send in a medical certificate, if not, then since this is not a life threatening situation, you can not lie about it and Allah knows best.